# Is there a way to shorten Riverpod dependency injection calls in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod for dependency injection in my Flutter project. It's a great package, but... these function calls are getting long and hard to read the more complex my project gets. Especially where I have some complex logic that depends on these calls.

What is a good way to shorten these long function/property calls?

Ideally would be to get it all the way back to the raw function call.

Complexity example:

```
if (saleKey != null) {
    await context.read(localServices).editSale(sale: updatedSale()!, saleKey: saleKey, userID: localID);
    await uuidBox.add(syncEvent.syncUUID);
    await context.read(masterSyncEventServices).addSyncEvent(syncEvent, localID);
} else {
    await context.read(localServices).addSale(updatedSale()!, localID);
    await uuidBox.add(syncEvent.syncUUID);
    await context.read(masterSyncEventServices).addSyncEvent(syncEvent, localID);
}
```

How to shorten these calls?

```
context.read(masterSyncEventServices).addSyncEvent(syncEvent, localID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final myProvider = context.read(masterSyncEventServices);
myProvider.addSyncEvent(syncEvent, localID);
```